# Set Array of Strings in tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've got a tableViewCell that I need to have an array passed into the tableViewCell but not just passed into a text label or something like that. I'll let my code show.

My TableViewController:

```swift
let subjectsDict = ["Spanish": ["Lesson 1", "Lesson 2"], "Math":["Problem set 1", "Problem set 2"], "Science": ["Lab"]]

let subjectArray = ["Spanish", "Math", "Science"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "subjectCell", for: indexPath) as? SubjectTableViewCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    cell.subjectList = subjectsDict[subjectArray[indexPath.row]]

    return cell
}
```

And my tableViewCell looks like this.

```swift
class subjectTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
        var subjectList: [String] = []

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style , reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setUpTable()
    }
    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setUpTable()
    }
    func setUpTable() {
        print(subjectList)
    }
        //other code for creating the cell
}
```

But when I print the subjectList from the subjectTableViewCell it prints `none`

Comment: Post code where you are trying to print subjectList

Comment: You need to show how you attempt to update the cell's content with the value of `subjectList`.

Comment: I did now! Sorry I didn't add that originally

Comment: This is normal that the `subjectList` is empty because the `setUpTable` is called when the cell is init or loaded, so before the `subjectList` has been set.

Comment: Ok I'll remember that . But I can see it's not being set because I'm using it to make a list in the cell and its not finding anything in the array to use to make the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes no attempt to update the cell's content with the value of `subjectList`. All you show is a `print`.

Also note that your `print` is called before any attempt to set `subjectList` is made. And remember that cells get reused. `setUpTable` will only be called once but `subjectList` will be set over and over as the cell gets used.

The simplest solution is to update the cell when `subjectList` is set.

```
var subjectList: [String] = [] {
    didSet {
        textLabel?.text = subjectList.joined(separator: ", ")
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you are using the standard `textLabel` property. If you have your own label then update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to invoke `setUpTable()` when your `subjectList` in the cell gets updated, try using:

```
var subjectList: [String] = [] {
    didSet {
        setUpTable()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print subjectList in the moment you initialise your table view cell so in this moment you haven't set subjectList yet. If you want to print subjectList you can do it after you set it.

After this line gets executed:

```
cell.subjectList = subjectsDict[subjectArray[indexPath.row]]
```